# datagridview bind combobox generated column

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I have a dataGridview in a winform connected to a SQL table "something". The column in the grid are auto generated by the dataset. I have set one of the column to not visible because I need that particular column to be a combo box column which I have added by code:

```
 DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboCol1 = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        comboCol1.Name = "foo1";
        List<DateTime> periods = new List<DateTime>() { DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1), DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1) };
        List<string> colSource = periods.Select(x => x.ToString("MMM/yyyy")).ToList();
        comboCol1.DataSource = colSource;
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(comboCol1);
        dataGridView1.Columns["foo1"].DisplayIndex = 1;
```

This combobox column has items generated by the above code and I would like to post the selected value to the column "xx"in table"something". I can I achieve that?

Comment: You need to set the name of the database column to `comboCol1.DataPropertyName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [`DataPropertyName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of dataGridView to bind column like:

```
 comboCol1.DataPropertyName = "foo1";
```